# PWM Modulator Circuit

Tags: pwm, 555

I want to generate a PWM signal from a potentiometer.

This must be a reliable circuit to be placed in a PCB. I've tried a 555 timer circuit in a breadboard ([this one](https://skinnyrd.com/adjust-the-duty-cycle-of-the-555-timer-without-changing-the-frequency/)), however, the results weren't great. The minimum PWM value I managed was 20%, and above 90% the frequency started decreasing, from 10kHz to around 7Hz at (almost) 100%.

Here is the circuit:
[image]

I used a 100k potentiometer, with 10k resistors, which means that, according to the math, I should have a PWM window of 8% to 92% (which is not excellent but acceptable).

I know there are other variations of this circuit, which I haven't tried yet, however, I was wondering if there was an IC that did this fairly simply. I found [this one](https://pt.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/LTC6992_1_6992_2_6992_3_6992_4-1270033.pdf), however, it costs 5€ and only accepts a Vin of 0 to 1V. Other similar ICs seemed fairly complex and I'm really in a hurry here.

[image]

Any cheap and reliable solutions for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Why would a 0 to 1 volt input range be a problem if you are using a potentiometer?

Comment: It's not a big deal, just found it strange. I would just have to step down the voltage from 3.3V to 1V. The problem is in the 5€ price tag, which is more expensive than buying an MCU.